# HTML code sent to Firefox via OutputStream in Java not recognized

Tags: java, html, firefox, outputstream

I have a simple application in **Java** that writes some `HTML` code to an `OutputStream`.

Running this and opening the connection with either Chromium or Opera works perfectly, whereas with Firefox the HTML code is not interpreted and displayed as is.

The string containing the code is like the following one:

```
HTMLCode = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<body>\n<h1>\n"
           + "The sum of " + operand1 + " and " + operand2 + " is " + result
           + "\n</h1>\n</body>\n</html>";
```

where `operand1`, `operand2` and `result` are `String`s.

I write to the `OutputStream` via the following code:

```
new PrintStream(out).println(HTMLCode);
```

Chromium and Opera correctly display, for instance, the following:

## The sum of 10 and 20 is 30

Firefox displays

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>
The sum of 2 and 34 is 36
</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sending a complete HTTP response(with headers), or just some HTML?

Comment: As you can see, I just send a `String` containing HTML code via the `OutputStream`.

Comment: Send the proper [html headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields). For instance `content-type`, `Status` and `Date`

Comment: @copeg Just curious to know. Chromium and Opera don't require a Content-Type header(and others) to interpret a response as HTML?

Comment: @kkaosninja Not all browsers are created equal

Comment: @copeg : Where do I send them? In the `OutputStream`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send the proper HTML headers before the actual content.

```
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(out);
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d, yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
ps.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
ps.println("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
ps.println("Date: " + df.format(new Date()));
ps.println("Connection: close");
ps.println();
ps.println(HTMLCode);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, things get worse, since even Chromium and Opera interprete this as text to be displayed as is.

Comment: You need to find the appropriate headers to use and modify them appropriately. Each browser will function a bit differently. See edit, which works for me in both firefox and chrome